# How to control a nil value returned from NSData(contentsOfURL: url) in Swift?

Tags: ios, nsdata, swift2

I want get data with a url in swift from php server. But when i use NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) I get nil, and my app broke with error: 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'. This is because my server Service is Temporarily Unavailable

My code is:

```
  let strURL: String = "http://domain.com/myphpfile.php?username="+userTF.text!+"&pass="+passTF.text!
    let url = NSURL(string: strURL)
    let dataURL = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)  //Here return nil
```

How can I control when my link returning nil I show a message but my app not close?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using forced-unwrapped values with `!`, safely unwrap with `if let` instead:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: strURL), let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
    // use `data` here
} else {
    print("something went wrong")
}
```

**Hint: don't use `NSData contentsOfURL` anyway, use something like `NSURLSession` instead.** This is because `contentsOfURL` blocks the main thread while working which freezes the UI and could result in the app being killed by iOS.